Crear un tmpfile usando un Input File en PHP
Actualmente envió un archivo (usando input file) a un AJAX PHP y lo uso a través de $_FILES['nombre']['nombre2'], para luego subirlo a mi servidor usando el método move_uploaded_file() de PHP, usar el archivo ya subido y al final eliminarlo del servidor
Me di cuenta que como al final elimino el archivo previamente subido quizás haya una mejor forma para usar el archivo sin tener que subirlo al servidor.
Saben si tmpfile puede almacenar un archivo de un input file?

Hola, que es un AJAX PHP ???

para que quieres el archivo ???

si lo envias en $_FILES siempre estara en un temporal ... por defecto ... no lo encontraras en ningun otro logar ...

lo que puedes hacer es leer el contenido de ese temporal y guardarlo en una variable ...

sigo preguntandome que es un AJAX PHP

@Benito-B te molesta?

si crees que no son necesarios puedes reportarlos.

Cuando digo AJAX PHP me refiero a una AJAX común y corriente que usa php

@– Francisco Nuñez IA Lover , el archivo lo uso para enviarlo adjunto en un correo usando la libreria PHPMailer.

@prox, un tmpfile es un archivo temporal, al cerrar el puntero al mismo el archivo se borra automáticamente. En otras palabras, no te va a servir.

@Marcos, oh, pensaba usarlo y luego cerrarlo....., una pena

@– Francisco Nuñez IA Lover, probé tu forma y funcionó!!, gracias!!!

Si alguna des las respuesta de fue util recuerda marcas esto como solucionado, saludos.

Ok. Ojala los comentario tuvieran esa opción

ok, primero que nada aclaremos los concepto AJAX es un acronimo para: Asynchronous JavaScript And XML y en javascript es el mecanismo de intercambio de datos/peticiones entre el frontend y el backend.
Nota: AJAX no tiene nada que ver con que se use o no php ... puede implementar AJAX con JAVA o ASP en el backend.
Segundo como tu AJAX envia al Backend (PHP) un archivo, este archivo como todo input sera almacenado temporalmente en algun lugar hasta que se elimine o finalice la ejecucion de la peticion/request, entonces la variable $_FILES['nombre']['nombre2'] debe ser accesible desdecualquier lugar.
Tercero, conociendo los puntos anteriores hay muchas forma de manipular el archivo $_FILES['nombre']['nombre2'] para adjuntarlo en PHPMailer si no necesitas la persistencia del archivo en el servidor, simplemente puedes ajuntarlo en el correo con:
    $archivo_temporal = $_FILES['nombre']['tmp_name']; // Ruta del archivo temporal
    $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['nombre']['name']; // Nombre original del archivo
    $mail->addAttachment($archivo_temporal, $nombre_archivo);

Nota: debes asegurarte de que a $_FILES tiene la estructura esperada para que se peudan adjuntar los archivos.

Esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta. Los dos primeros punto son para aclarar conceptos y el último es para proponer un solución alternativa. Es probable que esto deberían haberlo debatido en el chat.

No realmente , en otro chat ya había dicho que me sirvió lo que dijo y agradecí

@prox, disculpa pero como es que enviar el archivo por mail usando una librería que nunca se menciona es una respuesta a la pregunta Saben si tmpfile puede almacenar un archivo de un input file?

@Marcos lo que pasa es que los comentarios son para aclarar cosas ... relacionadas al post y yo le pregunte esto: para que quieres el archivo ???

@Marcos y el aclaro esto: Francisco Nuñez IA Lover , el archivo lo uso para enviarlo adjunto en un correo usando la libreria PHPMailer.

@Marcos entonces: POST + Comentarios + Aclaracion  = Buenas respuesta (Respuestas aceptadas)

@FranciscoNuñezIALover, ok, entonces eso es algo que ya lo hacía? Esto es raro,  no importa.

Como sea, lo que @Francisco Nuñez IA Lover, mencionó al principio me sirvió, gracias a ello puede usar el archivo sin tener que subirlo primero a una carpeta creada en mi servidor. En cuanto por que no mencioné sobre en que lo utilizaba, no me pareció redundante dado que quería utilizarlo dentro del AJAX.

@Marcos el estaba intentando hacerlo, pero no queria guardar el archivo para enviar el correo ...  y despues borrarlo. el concepto de AJAX o usarlo desde el AJAX era erroneo necesitaba aclaracion ...

al final use el temporal creado en $FILES['nombre']['tmp_name'][0] para poder usarlo sin tener que subirlo al servidor.
Para que se entienda mejor:
En el AJAX capturo en una variable el archivo a través de $_FILES, similar a como capturas los inputs de un formulario con $_POST.
$variableName = $FILES['nombre']['tmp_name'][0];

Y como ultimo lo llamo o uso referenciando al nombre de la variable, en este caso usando un metodo de PHPMailer donde puedo adjuntar el archivo.
addAttachment = Metodo para adjuntar un archivo (archivo, nombreDeArchivoPesonalizado )
$mail->addAttachment($fileTempFile,$fileFileName)


te acabo de responder lo mismo jajajajaja fijate como se elavora correctamente una respuesta ... ya que esto que acabas de decir a pesar de que es la respuesta no dice literalmente como lo hiciste ...

En realidad el archivo si se crea en el servidor, de lo contrario no podrías leerlo con PHP. El archivo se crea con un nombre temporal y en un directorio configurado para PHP. Depende de la configuración del servidor, los archivos en dicho directorio se borran cada cierto período de tiempo.

@Marcos pero a pesar de que el archivo se quede temporalmente en ese directorio, recuerda que el nombre original y el nombre temporal relacionados como tal ... solo viven durante el request ... si intenta en un request diferentes encontrar y manipular el archivo aunque el archivo exista no podra relacionarlos ...

@FranciscoNuñezIALover, si eso es correcto. Así es como toda información que se envía al BE... si no se guarda en algún lado... no se puede recuperar.

Acabo de actualizar respuesta y si, pondré tu respuesta como solución
